# Open sidemenu with scroll at the top

Tags: ionic3

My side menu has scroll, so when I scroll it all the way to the bottom and close it, I need it to reopen with the scroll position at the top.

Currently, I'm trying to access the side menu component from app.component.ts, but calling the scrollToTop method doesn't do anything.

```
// app.component.html
<ion-menu
  type="overlay"
  side="right"
  [swipeEnabled]="false"
  [content]="content"
  (ionClose)="sideMenuScrollTop()"
>
<sidemenu [nav]="nav"></sidemenu>
</ion-menu>
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content></ion-nav>

// app.component.ts
@ViewChild(SideMenuComponent)
sideMenu: SideMenuComponent;

sideMenuScrollTop() {
  this.sideMenu.content.scrollToTop();
}

// sidemenu.component.ts
@ViewChild(Content)
content: Content;
```